# Pandas DataReader Fails To Obtain Data for Mutual Funds and Indexes from Google

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

I have attempted to obtain financial data from google for certain financial indexes not available elsewhere.  The data extraction failed and has left me wondering if certain categories of google financial data cannot extracted using Pandas DataReader. I have googled the issue and cannot find any discussion of this issue. Is there a limitation of obtaining data from google finance?

Here is the problem. I received the following error when I attempted to obtain data from google finance using the Pandas's DataReader:

OSError: after 3 tries, Google did not return a 200 for url 'http://www.google.com/finance/historical?enddate=Dec+25%2C+2015&q=VFINX&startdate=Jun+02%2C+2003&output=csv'

The Pandas's statement causing the error message was:

```
data.DataReader("VFINX", 'google', start=datetime.datetime(2003, 6, 2), end=datetime.date.today())
```

I imported the following libraries:

```
from pandas_datareader import data, wb

import datetime
```

The error occurs also when I attempt to obtain data for a mutual fund, such as VFINX (Vanguard S&P 500), or an index, such as DWCPF (Dow Jones Completion Index). The obvious work around for mutual funds is to use Yahoo. However, the above statement works fine when I obtain data for a stock, such as C (Citibank).  This leads me to believe that Google finance data for mutual funds and indexes are not available thru the pandas data reader.

Unfortunately, the historical data for index DWCPF is not available from Yahoo.  To obtain the data from google I web scraped google by modifying the url,
https://www.google.com/finance/historical?cid=12645460&startdate=Dec+26%2C+2014&enddate=Dec+25%2C+2015&num=200&ei=TVV9VoHSOMWSmAGAx7ewCg
Clearly, web scraping is more work than using simply the data reader.

I am using python 3.4 (and 3.5 on another computer), pandas version 0.17.1, and recently upgraded to Pandas DataReader.

Comment: It looks like Google Finance does not support csv output for mutual funds.  So this url works: http://www.google.com/finance/historical?&q=VFINX but adding &output=csv with any &startdate or &enddate does not

Comment: This could be because mutual funds and indexes do not have trading prices (they have NAVs and levels, respectively), which Google may not have permission to provide for download.  Just a guess though.

Answer (score 1):

Google lists the [data providers](http://www.google.com/intl/en/googlefinance/disclaimer/) for the various securities and exchanges, and [so](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/finance/SLN2310.html?impressions=true) does Yahoo. While stock data come delayed from exchanges, mutual fund data come from `MorningStar` and `vickers-stock.com`, respectively.

The latter being commercial data providers (and so is Dow Jones) rather than stock exchanges, they will likely be more restrictive on the data usage beyond display on google/yahoo websites, and will likely have terms in the contracts to prevent large-scale downloads via API.

So in essence, you are most likely running into commercial limitations of the google finance api rather than technical limitations of the `pandas` `DataReader`.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I suspected that it was not a problem with the pandas DataReader.

Comment: Happy to help. Did this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, you did answer my question.  I appreciate your time effort to respond.